# inserting numpy data into a bigger array of zeros

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I would like to put data of a numpy array of any size from the start of another bigger array of zeros.

Looking at numpy documentation I found the function np.put but it gives me a problem like this:

Supossing

```
import numpy as np
b = np.zeros(5)
a = np.range(1,4)
np.put(b,a,a)
```

produces something in b like

> [0,1,2,3,0]

I also tried to use place function

```
np.place(b,b>len(a),a)
```

but nothing changes the matrix.

> [0,0,0,0,0]

If someone has already worked on this, his/her help would be really good now.

Comment: It's a bit difficult to understand the question, what is the behaviour you expect, and which command fails to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `np.put` incorrectly.

```
np.put(b, a, a)
#      ^  ^  ^
#      |  |  |
# Target  |  |
#   Indices  |
#       Values
```

You told `np.put` to place the values of `a` at positions defined by `a`.

Instead:

```
np.put(b, np.arange(len(a)), a)
```

or:

```
b[:len(a)] = a
```